# Form validation not checking against expression

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, i cant figure out where its broken. It operates as if it never checks the variables for the correct regex that is written. Any help figuring out where im going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>

function allNumbers( field, msg ) {
var numberexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
if ( field.value.match( numberexp ) ) {
   return true;
} else {
   alert( msg );
   field.focus();
   return false;
}
}

function allLetters( field, msg ) {
var letexp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
if ( field.value.match( letexp ) ) {
   return true;
} else {
   alert( Msg );
   field.focus();
   return false;
}
}

function notEmpty( field, msg ) {
if ( field.value.length == 0 ) {
   alert( msg );
   field.focus();
   return false;
}
return true;
}

function validateForm() {
    var a = document.getElementById('firstname');
    var b = document.forms["contactrecord"]["lastname"].value;
    var c = document.forms["contactrecord"]["phone"].value;
    var d = document.forms["contactrecord"]["address"].value;
    var e = document.forms["contactrecord"]["city"].value;
    var f = document.forms["contactrecord"]["state"].value;
    var g = document.forms["contactrecord"]["zip"].value;

   if ( allLetters( a, "Incorrect First Name" ) ) {
     if ( allLetters( b, "Incorrect Last Name" ) ) {
       if ( allNumbers( c, "Incorrect Phone Number" ) ) {
         if ( notEmpty( d, "Incorrect address" ) ) {
           if ( allLetters( e, "Incorrect City Name" ) ) {
             if ( allNumbers( g, "Incorrect Zip Code") ) {
                return true;
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of *match*, it's more appropriate to use *test*, e.g.: `numberexp.test(field.value)`. The number regular expression can be `/^\d+$/` or negated `/\D/` and the letters one `/^\w+$/` or negated `/\W/`.

Comment: @RobG that should not matter. You need to have a `name` attribute for `lastname`, `phone`, `address`, `city`, `state`, and `zip` in your HTML, like `<input name='lastname' />`. Do you?

Comment: @PHPglue—it's a comment, not a solution. A name is required if the form is submitted but ID may do. I'd rather work on the issues I can see rather than guess at what I can't.

Comment: yes i do have that name attribute in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how I would do it, but it's your code. You were passing the value of each form control whereas the functions are expecting a reference to a form control.

Note that the function now expects a reference to the form, so you can do something like:

```
<form onsubmit="validateForm(this);" ...>


function allNumbers(field, msg) {

  // If has a non-number character, return false
  if (/\D/.test(field.value)) {
    field.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// If value has a non-word character, return false
function allLetters(field, msg) {
  if (/\W/.test(field.value)) {
    field.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// If value has no characters, return false
function notEmpty(field, msg) {
  if (field.value.length == 0){
    alert(msg);
    field.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validateForm(form) {
  var a = document.getElementById('firstname');
  var b = form.lastname;
  var c = form.phone;
  var d = form.address;
  var e = form.city;
  var f = form.state;
  var g = form.zip;

  if (allLetters(a, "Incorrect First Name") &&
      allLetters(b, "Incorrect Last Name")  &&
      allNumbers(c, "Incorrect Phone Number") &&
      notEmpty(d, "Incorrect address") &&
      allLetters(e, "Incorrect City Name") &&
      allNumbers(g, "Incorrect Zip Code")
   ) { 
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're missing `name` attributes in your `input`s. Put them in there.